# 2d движок, где физический и графический объект - одно

Tags: android, ios, разработка-игр

В 3d движках (например unity3d) делаешь какой-то объект, ставишь ему текстуру и физ параметры - и всё, объект готов.

В тех 2d движках, которые я видел (например libgdx), всё гораздо сложнее:

1. создаётся отдельный физический мир с этим объектом
2. разработчик сам считывает координаты этого объекта
3. и сам рисует на полученных координатах то, что ему надо

Лично для моей игры такой подход создаёт очень много проблем, поэтому гораздо проще было бы использовать движок, который бы сам считал физику и рисовал, как это сделано в большинстве 3d движков.

Comment: Во первых - в чем вопрос? А во вторых, если нравится Unity3d, то в чем проблема использовать именно его? Он же ведь и 2D-движок одновременно. Довольно много 2D-игр сделанно на нем.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на box2d в libgdx .